# collectd network plugin (if_octets) download speed vs wget download speed

Tags: collectd, grafana

I set up `collectd`, `InfluxDB` and `Grafana` to monitor my servers.
I observed that Grafana shows (based on `collectd` network plugin) higher download speeds than `wget`.

I have stable 300 Mbps fiber connection. I chose Debian Stretch DVD as a testing file.

With `wget` I got maximum 37,6 MB/s (almost all the time), which is about 300 Mbps.

`collectd` network plugin reports `if_octets` every 10 seconds to `InfluxDB`. To get interface utilization I wrote the query (multiplication by 8 convert to bits from bytes):

```
select derivative("value", 1s) * 8 from interface_rx where type = 'if_octets'
```

The maximum values I got are:

```
1500155290145892000 3.293407499020192e+08
1500155300145869000 3.219917429810089e+08
1500155310146384000 3.2986061457834923e+08
1500155320146017000 3.2966692997633016e+08
```

Which means about 329 Mbps.

According to wget I was downloading this file with maximum allowed speed (300 Mbps) all the time, so `InfluxDB` 1 second `derivative` should get me the number of bytes gathered during this 10 seconds divided by 10, which should be about 300 Mbps.

I queried raw `if_octets`.

```
select value * 8 from interface_rx where type = 'if_octets'

1500188090410383000 1.1244408992e+10
1500188100410730000 1.4540160304e+10
1500188110411085000 1.783722016e+10
```

The difference between measurements are about `0.33e+10` bits, which is about `3300 Mb` per ten seconds, which is about `330 Mbps`.

Also, the difference between `1500188090410383000` and `1500188100410730000` timestamps is `0.001 s`, so this is not the issue (the difference between `3000 Mb` and `3300 Mb` is about 10%, so to blame `collectd` reporting times they should differ by about 10% too, which is about `1s`.)

This 329 Mbps value is faster than my connection speed limit and is different than accurate `wget` value. Does anybody know why?

K.

Answer (score 0):

Advertised bandwidths from network service providers are subject to:

(a) ease of understanding (300 is simpler than 329.7)

(b) 95th percentile metering (https://www.semaphore.com/95th-percentile-bandwidth-metering-explained-and-analyzed/)

(c) burstable billing

In other words, the "300" number they gave you when you signed your contract does not necessarily have to be accurate.

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting network overhead. `wget` reports payload bytes transferred, while interface statistics counters (that collectd uses) include Ethernet frames as well as IP and TCP headers, and count retransmitted packets.